# Where can I find custom Geometry Shapes?

Tags: wpf, geometry

I'm looking for resources (geometry shapes) for WPF
A website like iconfinder.com for instance...

Is there any website for this??

I'd like to have shapes replacing my icons like (save icon, new icon, ...)

Some examples :

```
<Path Stretch="Fill" Fill="Black"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                              Width="12" Height="12" Data="F1 M 151,217L 152,217L 154.5,219.5L 157,217L 158,217L 158,218L 155.5,220.5L 158,223L 158,224L 157,224L 154.5,221.5L 152,224L 151,224L 151,223L 153.5,220.5L 151,218L 151,217 Z">
            </Path>
            <Separator></Separator>
            <Path Data="M0,0 L8,0 8,1 8,2 0,2 0,1 z" Stretch="Uniform"  Fill="Black"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                              Width="12" Height="12"></Path>
            <Separator></Separator>
            <Path Data="F1 M 34,17L 43,17L 43,23L 34,23L 34,17 Z M 35,19L 35,22L 42,22L 42,19L 35,19 Z" Stretch="Fill" Fill="Black"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                              Width="12" Height="12"></Path>
            <Separator></Separator>
            <Path Stretch="Fill" Fill="Black"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                              Width="12" Height="12" Data="M1,4.9996096 L1,7.000219 7,6.999219 7,5.001 2,5.001 2,4.9996096 z M3,2.0014141 L3,3.0000001 8,3.0000001 8,4.0000001 8,4.0008045 9,4.0008045 9,2.0014141 z M2,0 L10,0 10,0.0010234118 10,1.0000001 10,5.001 8,5.001 8,7.9990235 0,8.0000239 0,4.0000001 0,3.0009998 0,3.0000001 2,3.0000001 2,1.0000001 2,0.0010234118 z"></Path>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this free tool called Metro Studio http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio
has a huge collection of icons that you can use in different formats (xaml being one of them)

You can also try http://www.xamalot.com/ which contains a lot of vector graphics

Comment: Have a look at MetroStudio as well. A powerful tool with loads of icons and more